How to account for destination being file or directory in cp implementation in c
I am writing a pseudo-shell in c for a class and my cp command needs to account for the destination being a file or a directory. I realized after I implemented everything I currently only truly account for a file name as destinationPath. How should I go about accounting for that?

void copyFile(char *sourcePath, char *destinationPath) {
    //cp command
    int srcCheck, destCheck, standardCheck;
    char* buff[1024];

    srcCheck = open(sourcePath, O_RDONLY);
    if (srcCheck < 0) {
        write(1, "Error with opening source\n", strlen("Error with opening source\n"));
        return;
    }

    destCheck = open(destinationPath, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);

    if (destCheck < 0) {
        close(srcCheck);
        write(1, "Error something went wrong with dest\n", strlen("Error something went wrong with dest\n"));
        return;
    }


    while ((standardCheck = read(srcCheck, buff, BUFSIZ)) != 0) {
        write(destCheck, buff, standardCheck);
    }

    if (standardCheck == -1) {
        write(1, "Error reading\n", strlen("Error reading\n"));
        return;
    }

    if (close(srcCheck) == -1) {
        write(1, "Error closing source\n", strlen("Error closing source\n"));
        return;
    }

    if(close(destCheck) == -1) {
        write(1, "Error closing dest\n", strlen("Error closing dest\n"));
        return;
    }

}


I already looked through a couple different cp implementations but couldn't find any that considered destination may be a directory

"I already looked through a couple different cp implementations but couldn't find any that considered destination may be a directory",- how is that? Did you really looked at any implementation? I doubt that.

Please [edit] your question and add links to the "couple different cp implementations". Then we can point you to the related code. Handle the return values of read and write correctly. Value -1 indicates an error, but you handle any non-zero value as success. write can also write less then you wanted to and will return the number of bytes or maybe an error indication. You might need to call write multiple times to get all data written. On errors you need to check errno. In case of EINTR (interrupted by signal) you should repeat the call. Functions from stdio.hmight be easier.

You can use the stat system call on your dest to distinguish what your destination is.
If it's a directory - copy file in that directory etc.
Read man stat.2 or man 2 stat.
Also, there is some weird things about your code.
Like, for example:
char* buff[1024];

1024 pointers to char. Why?
Compile your code with -Wall -Wextra -Werror. Just a good practice.
If you want to write to stdout - do not use 1 as a file descriptor. There is special STDOUT_FILENO macro. Use it.
If you have a literal string like "Error closing source" - you can use sizeof - 1 on it instead of strlen. Also, you have string duplication where. I'd suggest something like this:
#define ERR_OPEN "Error opening source\n"
...
write (STDOUT_FILENO, ERR_OPEN, sizeof (ERR_OPEN) - 1);

Or better yet:
fprintf (stderr, "Error opening source: %s\n", strerror (errno));

That way you can also print the reason of error. That's important.
Requires including errno.h for errno value and string.h for strerror.
Also, you should check every system call you are using. write is not an exception. Usually every system call that has glibc wrapper changes errno value to indicate what exactly happened. I'd recommend reading manual page for every system call you use.
UPD:
Dalija Prasnikar suggested to mention a possible race condition.
If you stat a certain file and then write to it - some other process can delete stat'ed file, or replace it with a link to some other file, just after you stat it.
If there is a need to avoid such a problem - you can first lock your dest and then do everything you need to do. That way other processes wouldn't be able to do anything while you are working on a file.
So, read on file locking in linux. I'd suggest a book called Advanced programming in Unix environment by Richard Stevens. It has everything you will ever need and more.

Checking the destination before operation starts has a race condition. What is there can be easily gone by the time actual operation takes place.

@DalijaPrasnikar You are correct, but OP probably doesn't care about this. I doubt that even built in cp utility in linux cares about this race condition.

Answers here are not just for the OP. And even if the race turns out to be not as important, it is important to warn about its existence to raise awareness.

@DalijaPrasnikar OP speaks of making a difference between directory and file. The answer tells how to know the difference. What will he do in case of possible change of the state on-the-fly is a different topic.

I do not think that you shall fall into over-compicating path suggested by @DalijaPrasnikar. Locking the dest is definetly not a way to go. Because it fails the user expectations.

I just checked my shell behaviour for the situation. And it does not speculate. I think any shell will not speculate on the topic of what will be the possible outcome. Because venturing that way is a path to fantasy land.

@user14063792468 since OP is doing it for a class - there is nothing wrong with a bit of complexity, if it will help him learn new things. Anyway - it's for OP to decide what suggestions to accept.

I shall simply repeat my previous comment. SO is an question-answer service. And the service has some rules. You are drifting from the topic. If, and when, OP will come to another problem, and he will have a better grasp of things then, he then could post another question. But for the present time you do over-design.

@Moses None of the mechanisms for file locking on Unix are capable of protecting against the race condition Dalija Prasnikar describes.
